# Quitar permisos de ejecucion archivo subido Java ee - Tomcat

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Estoy intentando hacer una web con Java EE que permite subir un archivo al servidor y luego descargarlo.
He logrado ambas cosas:
[Subir archivo a servidor Java ee](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28338/subir-archivo-a-servidor-java-ee)

Sin embargo, estoy teniendo un terrible hueco de seguridad. Los archivos se suben a C:\archivos
Pero si subo un archivo .jsp, por ej, es ejecutado por el servidor. (Pudiendo realizar cualquier tipo de consultas!). Lo que necesitaria saber, es la forma correcta de subir el archivo, o de editar los permisos, para que esto no pase. Para que se puedan descargar archivos, pero no ejecutar.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solucion. hay que hacer un servlet que se encargue de descargar el archivo. Para ello hay que remover el path del servlet.xml que habia agregado antes.

Subir:

```
    String subirArchivo(int codigo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    Part filePart = request.getPart("archivo"); // Obtiene el archivo
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.

    if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
        String path="/archivos/";
        File uploads = new File(path); //Carpeta donde se guardan los archivos
        uploads.mkdirs(); //Crea los directorios necesarios
        File file = File.createTempFile("cod"+codigo+"-", "-"+fileName, uploads); //Evita que hayan dos archivos con el mismo nombre

        try (InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream()){
            Files.copy(input, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        return file.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Post link:

```
if(adjunto!=null){
                String filename=adjunto.substring(10); //La longitud de /archivos/
                String borrar="<a href=borrarServlet?codigo="+codigo+"&comentario="+idComentario+"&file="+filename+"><img width=\"16\" src=images/borrar.png></img></a>";
                comentarios+="<tr><td>"+fecha+"</td>"+"<td>"+texto+"<br><a class=\"adj\" href=."+adjunto+">Descargar archivo</a></td><td>"+borrar+"</td></tr>";
            }
```

Descarga:

```
String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo().substring(1), "UTF-8");
File file = new File("/archivos", filename);
response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
```