# ¿Comó guardar una imagen en una carpeta uploads dentro de un proyecto con JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, servlets, payara

verán tengo el siguiente problema y estaría muy agradecido si me pudieran ayudar, la cosa es que cree un proyecto y cree una carpeta para guardar imágenes subidas por el usuario en WebContent->img->uploads pero no se como conseguir la ruta de esa carpeta, ya establecí el enctype a multipart/form-data y agregue @MultipartConfig en el servlet, también probé guiándome con:

[Subir archivo a servidor Java ee](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28338/subir-archivo-a-servidor-java-ee)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application/18664715#18664715

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

pero solo conseguí tomar la imagen y trabajarla en el servlet pero no guardarla.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
        String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.
        InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
        String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/uploads/");
        File img = new File(path, fileName);
        try (InputStream input = fileContent){
            Files.copy(input, img.toPath());
        }
        
            response.sendRedirect("HomeController.do");
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

PD: Uso Eclipse y Payara5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta de esta forma.

Primero que todo en el formulario tienes que tener el `enctype="multipart/form-data"` y el input donde se subieran los archivos tiene que ser de tipo "file":

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" />
</form>
```

**Nota:** Antes de esto muy importante tener la configuración del multipart habilita con los parámetros necesarios y la localización con la carpeta creada donde se almacenaran los archivos de manera temporal.

Luego de eso se procede a capturar la imagen:

```
String nameImage = multiPart.getOriginalFilename();
```

Busco el directorio donde quiero guardar mis imágenes:

```
String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/uploads/");
```

Creo un archivo concatenando la ruta donde quiero guardar las imágenes con el nombre:

```
File file = new File(path + nameImage);
```

Luego con este metodo de la clase `Multipart`guardo físicamente el archivo:

```
multiPart.transferTo(file);
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias por la respuesta.
Con tener la configuración te refieres a tener el @MultipartConfig?

Comment: Exacto, si es necesaria las dependencias y todo lo necesario para que funcione antes de ingresar el código.